# Dynamically query content of variables with index in the name

Tags: excel, vba

I have three string variables, `thisTemplateFrame1Type`, `hisTemplateFrame2Type`, `thisTemplateFrame3Type`.

They hold values such as `PVCV`, `ABS_Var` etc.

I have a loop that goes through these 3 (but `n` as it can be 1 to 3) variables and then based on a `Select Case` I want it to do things.

Example:

```
for i = 1 to {defined number of Frames}
   Select Case thisTemplateFrame1Type
      Case Is = "PVCV"
         [do stuff]
...
   End Select
Next i
```

Now this is tedious.

What I need instead is something like:

```
for i = 1 to {defined number of Frames}
   Select Case CStr("thisTemplateFrame" & meFrameCounter & "Type") 
  'this above should evaluate to say thisTemplateFrame1Type, thisTemplateFrame2Type...
      Case Is = "PVCV"
         [do stuff]
...
   End Select
Next i
```

That solution doesn't work because `CStr("thisTemplateFrame" & meFrameCounter & "Type")` always equals `thisTemplateFrame1Type` as a value but that basically means `thisTemplateFrame1Type <> PVCV` so the `Case` block moves on.

How do I pass the value properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically construct variable names in that way. You can however reframe (boom boom) your structure and loop an array of frames

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim frames(), frame As Variant, thisTemplateFrame1Type As String, thisTemplateFrame2Type As String, thisTemplateFrame3Type As String
    thisTemplateFrame1Type = "A"
    thisTemplateFrame2Type = "B"
    thisTemplateFrame3Type = "C"

    frames = Array(thisTemplateFrame1Type, thisTemplateFrame2Type, thisTemplateFrame3Type)

    For frame = LBound(frames) To UBound(frames)

        Select Case frames(frame)
        Case "A"

        Case "B"

        Case "C"
        End Select

    Next
End Sub
```